# Is a super-deterministic universe local or nonlocal?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-interpretations, bells-inequality, determinism, locality

Bell predicted *predetermined* (nonlocal) choice as the criteria for a super-deterministic universe.

> **...our belief that we are free to choose to do one experiment rather
> than another, absolutely predetermined** - The Ghost in the Atom: A Discussion of the Mysteries of Quantum Physics, by Paul C. W. Davies and Julian R. Brown, 1986/1993, pp. 45-46

However, I have read some physicists theorized that superdeterminism should be a local function determined by the experimenter not a nonlocal function predetermined by nature –  a super-deterministic universe as Bell predicted. [I have empirically tested for nonlocal superdeterminism and applied predetermined choice to the Higgs boson discovery](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012IJFPS...2...44M/abstract). However, I am not aware if anyone has *empirically* tested for local superdeterminism. Can the later be tested as proposed by [Sabine Hossenfelder](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.06462)?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145331/discussion-on-question-by-manuel-morales-is-a-super-deterministic-universe-local); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Wikipedia definition captures a good definition of superdeterminism:

> A hidden variables theory which is superdeterministic can thus fulfill Bell's notion of local causality and still violate the inequalities derived from Bell's theorem. This makes it possible to construct a local hidden-variable theory that reproduces the predictions of quantum mechanics,...

You can also check the reviews therein [1](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/47/42/424003) [2](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.92.021002).

The idea is that one of the assumptions of Bell's theorem is that of "free choice", i.e. that the conditional probability follows
$$p(\lambda|xy)=p(\lambda)$$
where $\lambda$ is the hidden variable and $x$ $y$ are the settings of the two detectors in a Bell test. Throwing out free choice is known as superdeterminism. Without it Bell theorem does not follow and cannot rule out a local hidden variables theory from explaining quantum mechanics.

Most superdeterminism models are thus built to retain locality in the sense of local hidden variables theory. See one of the first papers by [C. H. Brans 1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeterminism) or modern versions by [S. Hossenfelder](https://doi.org/10.1103%2FPhysRevA.106.022212). All papers I have found build local superdeterminism models.

Of course Bell's theorem does not hold also if you throw both free choice and locality, but it seems to be of little interest to the community. Superdetermisism is controversial enough as it is usually classified as untestable.

Let us avoid throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145330/discussion-on-answer-by-mauricio-is-a-super-deterministic-universe-local-or-nonl); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.